# Getting the title of a QListWidget item in PyQt5

Tags: xml, qt, pyqt, qlistwidget

This is probably a really simple question, but in my program I'm adding entries from an XML to a QListWidget. When a QListWidget item is selected, it triggers a change in a QLabel. I want the QLabel to have the same text as the QListWidget item. 
How would this be done?
Important Code: http://pastebin.com/90qDkdHe (permanent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QListWidget.currentItem` to retrieve the currently selected item and `text` returns it's text. So it could be like :

```
self.listWidget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.changeHackModifier)

def changeHackModifier(self):
    self.memtitle.setText(self.listWidget.currentItem().text())
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: It is because of a typo.It should be ` self.listWidget.currentItem().text()`. I edited the answer.